# Preloading with $(window).load() issue

Tags: jquery, preloader

I am using the following approach to Preload the content of my website:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#preLoader').hide();
    $('#container').show();
});
```

Now my #container div contains all my website content. I don't want this to be shown until my body background image has completely loaded...So while the background image is loaded, the #preLoader div displays with an animated loader gif inside.

**The issue:**

There are some elements that do not always load (eg gravatars) due to the Server containing the resource not being available...so the `$(window).load()` function never executes since the page has not finished loading - it it stuck at trying to download a resource that is not available and keeps displaying the loader.

How do I ignore requests that takes too long to respond so that my load function can execute - hide the loader and show the content.

I do not want to use the `$(document).ready()` function, since it does not wait until my background image has finished loading...

Comment: how about using load event for that particular background image element  only instead of the window. `$('#divcontainingbackgournimage').load(function(){..`

Comment: yeah, but what if you have many other elements you want to have finished loading before you display your content...? The only way then to target them individually?

Comment: @bipen DIVs don't have a load event even any background-image has been setted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just trying to preload the background image, you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#preLoader').show();
    $('#container').hide();

    $('<img>', {src: '/url/of/image.jpg'}).load(function() {
        $('#preLoader').hide();
        $('#container').show();
    }).error(function() {
        // Something went wrong
    });
});
```

A better alternative would be to use the [waitForImages plugin](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#preLoader').show();
    $('#container').hide();

    $(document).waitForImages(function() {
        $('#preLoader').hide();
        $('#container').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: yeah I guess I can do that. What if there are many more elements you want to wait for to finish loading?

Comment: @DextrousDave: There's a plugin you can use: https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages

Comment: thanks for your help. Any other way to do this without using plugin?

Comment: @DextrousDave: The minified plugin is absolutely tiny. It's 1000 characters long, which is only four times longer than my first example

Answer (score 0):

You should try some trick.
Make change in your page source for all elements like gravatar:

```
<img data-src="http://some-very-busy-resource.org/avatar.jpg" />
```

See, it is no "src" attribute presents, browser definetly doesn't load this image and page loads fast, you script shows the body as you expect.

Then, to load ignored images add this code:

```
   $('body').find('img').each(function(){
        src = $(this).data('src');

        if ('undefined' !== typeof src) {
            $(this).attr('src', src);   
        }
    });
```

So, new script should be like next:

```
$(function(){
    $('#preLoader').hide();
    $('#container').show();
    $('body').find('img').each(function(){
        src = $(this).data('src');
        if ('undefined' !== typeof src) {
            $(this).attr('src', src);   
        }
    });
});
```